# If all built-in types are immutable in C#, doesn't it mean that after assigning them a new value their memory location should change?

Tags: c#, immutability

I'm struggling with understanding concept of mutable and immutable types in C# I thought they cannot be changed "in place", only that new variable (with the same name? ) is created and edited value is assigned to it. Doesnt it mean it shoud have different memory location? I experimented with it in VS2015 but it appears not...

```
unsafe
{
    int a = 7;
    int* test = &a;

    Console.WriteLine(a);                
    Console.WriteLine((int)test);
    a+=5;
    test = &a;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine((int)test);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It outputs:

```
7
107604264
12
107604264
```

Comment: @JohnWu `int` is _not_ mutable. There is a new instance assigned every time. `a+=5` does _not_ change _the_ `int` in `a`, it's _assigning_ the result of the + operator. What maybe confusing in this topic is that there are two distinctions to make: mutable vs immutable and value vs. reference type. Since `int` is a value type, the new value of the variable `a` is always stored in the same place (`a`'s location in memory)

Comment: @RenéVogt so in case of reference type immutable types new instance is stored in new memory location but with the same name? so what's the difference really between mutable and immutable variable types then? it breaks my brain:D

Comment: As a side note, I'd suggest that the value of `test` being the same is somewhat of an implementation detail. You certainly shouldn't **rely** on it. I suspect it is largely a side-effect of the variable being on the stack. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Comment: I'm not so sure where this "value types are immutable" didactic came from, it is very unhelpful to understand immutability.  I suppose that programmers recognized that a parameter passed to a method can be mutated without affecting the argument value in the caller.  But that has nothing to do with immutability, everything to do with copying.  Get ahead by just ignoring such a claim if that helps you understand it better.

Comment: @mjwills I understand reference and value types pretty well actually ( i think:D). I just don't understand how, as cited in my book - "all built-in types are immutable" when since I started programming I've been changing my int, doubles, floats at will.. I guess mutable types are capable of being changed without assigning new value to variable? if that's true whats really the difference for me if, under the hood, compiler assigned new value to change it or changed it "in place"?

Comment: Note that I see why you _think_ you been altering existing ones based on your program (because `test`'s value stayed the same). But that isn't because you `altered` the 7. That was because the `7` was stored in the stack at a specific position in memory. Then you **assigned** a new value to the `a` **variable**. So, it stores that new value **in the same position on the stack** (which is an implementation detail, but it is what it does) - which makes sense, it doesn't need to store the old 7 any more.

Comment: So, in summary. `If all built-in types are immutable in C#, doesn't it mean that after assigning them a new value their memory location should change?` No, no it doesn't.

Comment: @mjwills both, if u could explain or show me direction

Comment: I'll try and give an analogy to explain what you are seeing (it isn't perfect, but we'll see how we go). Let's assume that diamonds are immutable (can't be changed). I get a box. I put a diamond in it. Then I take the diamond out of the box and put the new diamond in it. That is what you are doing. You are looking at the box, and saying 'there is still something there, I must have changed the first diamond'. But you didn't. You just put a **new** diamond where the old diamond used to be.

Comment: Immutability means one thing and one thing only - that an object of a specific type **cannot be changed**. That is all it means (so, for example, the fact that `string` is immutable means you can't change a string). It promises nothing about memory addresses / stack (the box). Therefore it can reuse memory addresses (which it does). Or, tomorrow, it could choose not to. It is an implementation detail that you don't need to care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're confusing variables with values.  A variable is just a name for a place that can store a value (for value types) or a reference to a value (for reference types).  For the purpose of our discussion here, it doesn't matter how/where that variable is stored, as we're talking about immutability of *values*.

When you assign the value '7' to an integer variable, that value '7' will always be '7'.  There is nothing you can do in your code that it ever make it be something other than '7'.  What would it mean if it were mutable?  That would be like changing a '7' to a '12' and then every other variable in your program that previously contained a '7' now containing a '12' instead.

This is a bit clearer if you look at an immutable reference type instead, like 'string'.  If I set `a = "Test"`, `b = a`, `a = "Test2"`, the value of b will still be "Test".  It's not normally possible to change the content of the string (without violating invariants by doing things like sneakily accessing private memory), so we call string values immutable.  You can rely on the fact that once a string reference has been stored into a variable, the string value it refers to will never change.

Answer (score 0):

> An object is immutable if its state doesn’t change once the object has been created.

It is just about the **state** and that is the point. IMO mutability/immutability is not related to the type but to the instance, so the instance is mutable or immutable. Generally, if you state type is immutable it means all instances of that type are immutable. The confusion could come from `reference` vs `value` types but generally, both could be mutable or immutable, even though it is highly recommended to keep `value` types immutable.

---

```
public class Immutable
{
    public int X {get; private set;}

    public Immutable(int x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
}

public class Mutable
{
    public int X {get; set;}

    public Mutable(int x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
}
```

nobody actually prevents you to change the reference of the object of the immutable class it is still immutable because you actually cannot change the **state**.

```
//the state can be changed Mutable
Mutable m = new Mutable(1);
m.X = 2; 

//the state cannot be changed
Immutable obj1 = new Immutable(1);
Immutable obj2 = new Immutable(2);
obj1 = obj2;
```

---